# How to typedef structs in C in a non-standard way

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I have a problem with typedefing the struct in C in a non-standard way.

I'm writing my own kernel.

```c
struct Time {
    int sec;
    int min;
    int hour;
    int monthDay;
    int month;
    // Year count from 1900
    int year;
    // Week day <0; 6>; 0 - sunday...6 - saturday
    int weekDay;
    // Year day is counted from 0
    int yearDay;
    // If > 0 then there is summer time, if 0 then there is standard time,
    // if < 0 then there isn't info about time
    int timeZone;
};

typedef struct Time struct tm;     // Doesn't work :(((
```

I have a compilation error right here. I wanted to define struct Time variables in a two ways:

- `struct Time a;`
- `struct tm b;`

I want to have ability to write struct before `tm b;` because I want to mark that type tm is a struct rather than simple primitive type.

Comment: Why don’t you want to do it the standard way, that works?

Comment: What are you really trying to do? What is the actual problem you need to solve? Please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), as well as about [the XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) (since your question is one).

Comment: I want to have ability to define variables of this structure in two separate ways as I described in question.

Comment: If you do `typedef struct Time tm` then you can declare one like `tm b;`. Why don’t you want that?

Comment: I want to have ability to write struct tm b; instead of simply tm b;

Comment: You're aware of the *standard C* structure [`tm`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/tm)? Why do you want to replace it? Again, what is the ***real*** problem you need to solve by "overloading" the standard `tm` structure?

Comment: Why do you think that is better?

Comment: I'm writing an operating system, that's why I won't overload standard tm structure from time.h

Comment: Then please update your question to include the details of why you want this and what you're doing. And even so, why do you want to use `struct tm`? If you're writing your own OS kernel (which is different from the more generic term "operating system"), why does it matter what your internal structures are called? If it's for some public API why can't you use the standard `tm` structure? Why can't you use it yourself internally?

Comment: I gave more details in question (edited it).

Comment: If you want `struct tm` why don't you simply define `struct tm` instead of `struct Time`? `typedef` is mainly used to remove the need to write `struct` and can only define an identifier name, not two.

Comment: To be honest, you say you want to use `struct tm` because you want to use `struct tm`. That's really no reason, and you still haven't told us *why* you want it, or what problem (*if any*) that's supposed to solve. We can only conclude that you don't really have a reason beyond being stubborn and that there's really no specific problem you need to solve.

Comment: @Gerhardh So I can't define structure variables of this struct in two ways?

Comment: you can define variables in lots of ways. But if you insist on using `struct` then you need to stick with 1 type. Having 2 names for the same thing is not really a good idea in most cases.

Comment: Oh, ok, that solves my doubts. Thanks @Gerhardh a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is strange in many ways. I cannot see a good usecase, but since you asked I'll provide a solution. But I will **strongly** discourage doing like this.

```
#define tm Time

struct Time {
    int sec;
};

struct Time a;
struct tm b;
```

Solving this with regular typedefs is not possible.